# Можно ли в условии WHERE подзапроса использовать LIKE + значение поля основного запроса?

Tags: mysql, select, like

Есть 2 таблицы:

*test*

[image: таблица test]

*test2*

[image: таблица test2]

Задача: сгруппировать по первой таблице, чтобы осталось по 1 фрукту. И прибавить к ним сумму фруктов из второй таблицы. Проблема в том, что во 2-й таблице Банан может быть в середине строки. Взять сумму там, где слово точно совпадает, получается:

```
SELECT food,
(SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM test2 WHERE test2.foods = test.food) AS foodsum
FROM test
GROUP BY food
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно посчитать не только полные совпадения `=`, но и `LIKE`:

```
Апельсин   16
Банан      13
```

Насколько я понимаю, здесь не получается использовать 'LIKE' и поле `test.food`. Можно ли как-то выйти из ситуации и при этом обойтись только средствами mysql? Реальная база имеет другие поля, но смысл тот же. Структуру таблиц трогать нельзя (база сделана плохо но работать надо с ней).

Comment: Замените условия на WHERE test2.foods like  cast ('%'+test.food+'%' as varchar (50))

Comment: Или же используйте instr - WHERE instr (test2.foods,test.food)>0

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis В MySQL нельзя оператором `+` конкатенировать строки. Можно только функцией concat: `test2.foods like concat('%',test.food,'%')` и cast не нужен

Comment: @Mike писал о mysql, думал о ms sql:) спасибо, что исправили.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать! =)

Comment: `like concat('%',test.food,'%')` и `WHERE instr (test2.foods,test.food)>0` идеально работают, спасибо! c `instr` все ясно, а вот конкатенация... как это работает - вообще не пойму... что cast, что concat... получается, конкатенируются части регулярного выражения как бы?

Comment: Да, они просто собирают строку вида `%апельсин%` а like на ней работает как обычно, `%` обозначают любые символы (P.S. выражения для like не принято называть регулярными выражениями, у регулярных выражений синтаксис другой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С решением помогли в комментариях, огромное спасибо. На всякий случай напишу в виде ответа:

1 вариант — использовать `concat`

```
SELECT food,
(SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM test2 WHERE test2.foods like concat('%',test.food,'%')) AS foodsum
FROM test
GROUP BY food
```

2 вариант — использовать `instr`

```
SELECT food,
(SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM test2 WHERE instr(test2.foods, test.food) > 0) AS foodsum
FROM test
GROUP BY food
```